# Android onItemSelected Null PointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I get this error message from my Users of my Android App fairly consistently even though I have not been able to replicate from my tests.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.MealOne$4.onItemSelected(MealOne.java:2172)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:882)
at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:865)
at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1017)
at android.widget.AdapterView.handleDataChanged(AdapterView.java:999)
at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:179)
```

Here is code snippet (line 2172 is "setTextColor(Color.WHITE);:

```
spinnerCarbs.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView,
                        View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    String selection = parentView.getItemAtPosition(
                            position).toString();

                    ((TextView) spinnerCarbs.getChildAt(0))
                            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ((TextView) spinnerCarbs.getChildAt(0))
                            .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    carbsSelection = selection;
                    carbsSpinnerPosition = spinnerCarbs
                            .getSelectedItemPosition();
                    savePrefs("CARBS", carbsSpinnerPosition);
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either spinnerCarbs is null, or its empty so its 0th child is null.  If you want to code defensively, do

```
                if(spinnerCarbs != null && spinnerCarbs.getChildAt(0) != null){
                    ((TextView) spinnerCarbs.getChildAt(0))
                            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    ((TextView) spinnerCarbs.getChildAt(0))
                            .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }
```

Comment: makes sense, I'll implement.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
if(spinnerCarbs == null) return;
```

Then the rest of you code